# Non-thread-safe Attempt to Implement Put-if-absent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

There is one code snippet in the 4th chapter in Java Concurrency in Practice

```
public class ListHelper<E> {
    public List<E> list =
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());
    ...
    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
        if (absent)
            list.add(x);
        return absent;
    }
}
```

it says this is thread safe for using different locks, ***putIfAbsent is not atomic relative to other operations on the List.***
But I think "synchronized" preventing multithreads enter putIfAbsent, if there are other methods that do other operations on the List, key word synchronized should also be as the method atttribute. So following this way, should it be thread safe? Under what case "it is not atomic"?

Comment: For future reference. Always make objects you lock on private, so no external code could lock on them without you knowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> putIfAbsent is not atomic relative to other operations on the List. But I think "synchronized" preventing multithreads enter putIfAbsent

This is true but there is no guarantees that there are other ways threads are accessing the `list`.  The `list` field is `public` (which is always a bad idea) which means that other threads can call methods on the `list` directly.  To properly protect the list, you should make it `private` and add `add(...)` and other methods to your `ListHelper` that are also `synchronized` to fully control *all* access to the synchronized-list.

```
// we are synchronizing the list so no reason to use Collections.synchronizedList
private List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
...
public synchronized boolean add(E e) {
    return list.add(e);
}
```

If the list is `private` and all of the methods are synchronized that access the list then you can remove the `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` since you are synchronizing it yourself.

> if there are other methods that do other operations on the List, key word synchronized should also be as the method atttribute. So following this way, should it be thread safe?

Not sure I fully parse this part of the question.  But if you make the `list` be `private` and you add other methods to access the list that are all `synchronized` then you are correct.

> Under what case "it is not atomic"?

`putIfAbsent(...)` is not atomic because there are multiple calls to the synchronized-list.  If multiple threads are operating on the list then another thread could have called `list.add(...)` between the time `putIfAbsent(...)` called `list.contains(x)` and then calls `list.add(x)`.  The `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` protects the list against corruption by multiple threads but it cannot protect against race-conditions when there are multiple calls to list methods that could interleave with calls from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Any unsynchronized method that modifies the list may introduce the absent element after list.contains() returns false, but before the element has been added.

Picture this as two threads:

```
boolean absent = !list.contains(x); // Returns true
-> list.add(theSameElementAsX);     // Another thread
if(absent)   // absent is true, but the list has been modified!
   list.add(x);
return absent;
```

This could be accomplished with simply a method as follows:

```
public void add(E e) {
    list.add(e);
}
```

If the method were synchronized, there would be no problem, since the add method wouldn't be able to run before putIfAbsent() was fully finished.

A proper correction would include making the List private, and making sure that compound operations on it are properly synchronized (i.e. on the class or the list itself).

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedList()` creates a collection which adds synchronization on private mutex for every **single** method of it. This mutex is `list` `this` for one-argument factory used in example, or can be provided when two-argument factory is used. That's why we need an external lock to make subsequent `contains()` and `add()` calls atomic.

In case the list is available **directly**, not via `ListHelper`, this code is broken, because access will be guarded by different locks in that case. To prevent that, it is possible to make `list` private to prevent direct access, and wrap all neccesary API with synchronization on the same mutex declared in `ListHelper` or on the `this` of `ListHelper` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is not composable!  Imagine a program built entirely out of "thread safe" classes.  Is the program itself "thread safe?"  Not necessarily.  It depends on what the program does with those classes.

The synchronizedList wrapper makes each individual method of a List "thread safe".  What does that mean?  It means that none of those wrapped methods can corrupt the *internal structure* of the list when called in a multi-threaded environment.

That doesn't protect the way in which any given program *uses* the list.  In the example code, the list appears to be used as an implementation of a set:  The program doesn't allow the same object to appear in the list more than one time.  There's nothing in the synchronizedList wrapper that will enforce that particular guarantee though, because that guarantee has nothing to do with the internal structure of the list.  The list can be perfectly valid as a list, but not valid as a set.

That's why the additional synchronization on the putIfAbsent() method.